# Is the Bullet physics engine completely deterministic?

Tags: physics

Suppose I set a wrecking-ball to crash into a configuration of stacked cubes. Now I set the scene in motion and record where each cube settles. I then create exactly the same scene again, with cubes and the wrecking ball in exactly the same configuration as before. Will the data I collected on the first simulation about the final position of cubes be EXACTLY the same as the data I collect the second time around, or will there be fundamental uncertainty?

Comment: From what I have observed: Yes, the Bullet physics engine is completely deterministic. What you describe with "create exactly the same scene again" is a pretty common use-case where we use a Python script to build the scene.